# Chained ostream internal behavior and their results on MSVC (versus Clang)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-templates, operator-precedence, post-increment

> *An issue of streams, internal string, and operation ordering with MSVC versus GCC / Clang*

Hello everyone,

I just recently began to work more seriously with MSVC for a cross-platform project of mine, and while testing outputs via *chained* STD stream (*ie. a succession of `obj.foo() << endl << obj.bar() << endl << [..etc]`*) I came across a behavior when using internally updated string neither did I expected nor had encountered on Linux with *GCC* or *Clang*.

Compiler versions were GCC 7.5, Clang 11.0 and MSVC 14.0, all with c++17 standard enabled (albeit not completed). [***edit**: same issue using  MSVC 16.6.3 (compiler internal version 19.26.28806.0)* ]

For a quick understanding here a simplified version of the issue :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

class Sample {
    std::string s;
    int x;

public:
    Sample() = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sample& a);

    // Update internal value, return the object.
    Sample const& set(std::string ss, int xx) { 
        s = ss; 
        x = xx;  
        return *this; 
    }
    
    // Update internal value, return the string.
    std::string const& setStr(std::string ss, int xx) { 
        set(ss, xx);  
        return s; 
    }
    
    // Update internal value, return the int.
    int const& setX(std::string ss, int xx) { 
        set(ss, xx);  
        return x; 
    }
};

// Output the object integer, same behavior with the string
// or if we flush inside or anything.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Sample const& a)
{
  os << a.x;
  return os;
}

int main() {
    Sample a;
                                                 // GCC / Clang  |    MSVC   
    std::cerr << a.set("0", 0) << std::endl      // 0                 0
              << a.set("1", 1) << std::endl      // 1                 0
              << a.set("2", 2) << std::endl;     // 2                 0

    std::cerr << "content : " << a << std::endl; // 2                 0
    
    a.set("",-1); std::cerr << std::endl;

    std::cerr << a.setStr("0", 0) << std::endl   // 0                 0
              << a.setStr("1", 1) << std::endl   // 1                 0
              << a.setStr("2", 2) << std::endl;  // 2                 0

    std::cerr << "content : " << a << std::endl; // 2                 0
    
    a.set("",-1); std::cerr << std::endl;

    std::cerr << a.setX("0", 0) << std::endl     // 0                 0
              << a.setX("1", 1) << std::endl     // 1                 1
              << a.setX("2", 2) << std::endl;    // 2                 2

    std::cerr << "content : " << a << std::endl; // 2                 2
}
```

It appears that with the string or streamed out version all operations use the same final mutated string object, but I can't figure why so (*again, with no problem on GNU / Linux toolchains*).

I might add that if we unchain the streams this ordering problem disappear :

```cpp
    std::cerr << a.set("0", 0) << std::endl; // "0"
    std::cerr << a.set("1", 1) << std::endl; // "1"
    std::cerr << a.set("2", 2) << std::endl; // "2"
```

I first thought it was a flushing problem, but tests shown otherwise. Actually using `endl` or even `flush` in between each chained call does nothing.

It might be a Visual-C++ or even *CPP101* known basic behavior (on memory and whatnot) but I had found nothing about it, so I'll be greatly grateful for any advice you could have as it's pretty darn strange in my book.

Thanks !

**Edit**

I have been able to reproduce the problem on GNU / Linux (with my project, not the above code) ironically trying to find an alternative via template variadic expansion, but here the things :

```cpp
void println() // base function
{
  std::cerr << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr void println(T head, Ts... tail)
{
  std::cerr << head << std::endl;
  println(tail...);
}

int main()
{
  int i;

  i = 0;
  println(++i, ++i, ++i); // 3 3 3
  i = 0;
  println(i++, i++, i++); // 2 1 0
}
```

On MSVC the stream seem to work like this post-increment variadic template : the results are somehow backward (or more like post recursively applied). I am not sure it made sense to me.

Comment: If I'm reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019 correctly, the [c++17 evaluation order changes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) aren't implemented until 15.7. 14 isn't good enough.

Comment: @user4581301 that sounds worthy of an answer.

Comment: Agreed. I just needed to do a bit more reading to confirm I was reading it correctly.

Comment: I came across something similar, just finished updating Visual Studio, I still got the same error (but thanks).

Comment: After installing Visual Studio 2017 did you do a few rounds of updating to make sure it's not merely 15.0, 15.03 or 15.5? You've made certain that  /std:c++17 or /std:c++latest is set?

Comment: I'm pretty sure but I will triple check everything (and the updates). If someone sure of his/her setup could cross-test the provided code on the side it could be nice.

Comment: Your additional edit is different. In that case, the `println(i++,i++,i++)` call is still unsequenced, even in c++17. But in your first case, seems like an msvc bug.

Comment: @cigien Yes this was to point out the behavorial similitude with what I've got with streams (even if I suspected variadic templates to work differently). That's probably a bug, thanks for you insight.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019), C++17's [changed evaluation order rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) were not implemented until VS 2017 15.7. 14.0 is not good enough. You will have to upgrade or not chain.

Testing

```cpp
#include <iostream>


int f()
{
    static int i = 0;
    return i++;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f() << f();
}
```

Should produce  01 after C++17

Without turning on C++17 support (Properties->Configuration Properties->Language->C++ Language Standard = default) I get 10, the functions are evaluated in reverse.

With Properties->Configuration Properties->Language->C++ Language Standard = ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17) I get the expected 01.

But if I run the asker's code... I still see the incorrect response. Removing most of the example and adding in an extra debug line (and replacing `cerr` with `cout` to see if there's some deep magic there) I get

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

class Sample {
    std::string s;
    int x = 0;

public:
    Sample() = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sample& a);

    // Update internal value, return the object.
    Sample const& set(std::string ss, int xx) {
        std::cout << "in func with " << ss << std::endl;
        s = ss;
        x = xx;
        return *this;
    }
};

// Output the object integer, same behavior with the string
// or if we flush inside or anything.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Sample const& a)
{
    os << a.x;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Sample a;
    // GCC / Clang  |    MSVC   
    std::cout << a.set("0", 0) << std::endl      // 0                 0
        << a.set("1", 1) << std::endl      // 1                 0
        << a.set("2", 2) << std::endl;     // 2                 0

    std::cout << "content : " << a << std::endl; // 2                 0
}
```

and output

```
in func with 2
in func with 1
in func with 0
0
0
0
content : 0
```

Clearly being called backwards. I have to ditch this and get some paid work done, but either I'm misreading

> 19. In a shift operator expression `E1<<E2` and `E1>>E2`, every value computation and side-effect of `E1` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E2`

([Quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)) or there's something fishy going on.

Comment: Thanks, but the update change nothing, I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Smurf. @Saachz All I have available is VS 2015 and can confirm it doesn't work there, as expected. Spinning up a VM to throw 2019 community on.

Comment: Well thanks, the up-to-date version still seem to have the issue though (on my side). Here's a nice version of the same data btw : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance.md

Comment: I just about have 2019 downloaded and installed. Then I can see for myself. The problem should be visible with a simple `std::cout << i++ << i++;` If it isn't, then something else is going wrong.

Comment: I might be wrong with the `i++` gag. I think I should be right, but g++ is still swearing at me and I get the wrong answer. I could be missing some subtlety. Replaced it with a function call. Updating answer

Comment: Thanks for this, I just woke up and it is still eluding me. Well we'll get to the bottom of it eventually.

Comment: Looks like msvc bug. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce; can't find an online compiler which executes msvc.