# Cout printing with array pointers - weird behavior

Tags: c++, increment, cout

I was playing around with pointers and got results I did not expect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int* pArr = arr;
    std::cout << "First number: " << *pArr << " at address: " << pArr;
    pArr++;
    std::cout << "\nSecond number: " << *pArr << " at address: " << pArr;
    pArr++;
    std::cout << "\nThird number: " << *pArr << " at address: " << pArr;
    pArr++;
    std::cout << "\nFourth number: " << *pArr << " at address: " << pArr;
    
    int* pArr2 = arr;
    std::cout << "\n"
        << *pArr2++ << "\n"
        << *pArr2++ << "\n"
        << *pArr2++ << "\n"
        << *pArr2++ << "\n";
    /*
    int* pArr2 = arr;
    std::cout << "\n"
        << ++ * pArr2 << "\n"
        <<  * ++pArr2 << "\n";
    */
}
```

The two different results:

`1 2 3 4` - as expected using the first method

`4 3 2 1` - using `cout` with multiple arguments *I do not know the proper name*.

So my question is - why does this happen? Using multiple `cout` statements results in expected *for me* code, while using just 1 `cout` results in backwards solution.

[image: Results screencap]

As a side note, another confusing thing to me is that pre-increment results in all values being equal. In the commented bit of code, the result is `3 3`, no matter the `++` placement with respect to the `*`.

Comment: Which compiler and version of C++ are you using?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I was using Visual Studio, and whatever c++ version was default - switched to newest and started working as commenter below pointed out. Thank you for your link also - got some reading to do :^)

Comment: By default MSVC is C++14

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
std::cout << "\n" << *pArr2++ << "\n";
std::cout << "\n" << *pArr2++ << "\n";
```

has a well defined order of modifications to `pArr` and will print

```
1
2
```

But this code:

```
std::cout << "\n" << *pArr2++ << "\n" << *pArr2++ << "\n";
```

invokes undefined behavior before c++17, because there are multiple modifications to `pArr2` that are unsequenced. The program has UB, so it could print anything.

From c++17, there is a sequence point between the modifications, and the above code is guaranteed to print:

```
1
2
```

Comment: cigien, do me a favour and take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666619/chained-ostream-internal-behavior-and-their-results-on-msvc-versus-clang if you have the time. I've been trying to figure out for the past few days if the asker's tripped over a bug in MSVC or if I've missed something.